# I have a repeating background square image of 89x89px which I'd like to change to a random coloured image when the mouse hovers

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, background

I would only like the current image to change colour though and reset after the mouse is moved off that particular image.

This will then cause a nice multi coloured pattern as the mouse is moved over the repeating images.

Thanks for your help in advance. A fiddle would be great!

Comment: by random colored image do you mean a random color background or an actual image that will have a random color in it?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

**CSS**

```
.foo {
    background: url('image1.png') repeat top left;
}

.foo:hover {
    background: url('image2.png') repeat top left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: `after the mouse is moved off` I think this wouldn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I would use webkit filter for that (but thats me and I love webkit browsers and live in hope that one day all the browsers will support it).

Something like:

```
img {
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
     transition: all 5s ease;
}

img:hover {
     -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(333deg);
}
```

But again it depends what exactly you want to achieve.
Here, take a look at this short tutorial that I wrote about images and on hover effect. Maybe it gets some ideas flowing, and you can play with the examples in your browser as they are hosted on codepen.

http://fivera.net/simple-cool-live-examples-image-hover-css-effect/